# Python - lxml - get current url address

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

I am trying to create a program to gather informatiom about trending prices from https://www.cardmarket.com/en/Magic with Python, lxml and request.

I managed to gather all necessary data except one case. When there is a card from only 1 extension e.g. Hagra Diabolist, website will reroute the address to https://www.cardmarket.com/en/Magic/Products/Singles/Zendikar/Hagra-Diabolist  even when you provided: https://www.cardmarket.com/en/Magic/MainPage/showSearchResult?searchFor=HagraDiabolist

Is there a way to check if the current address of the lxml request is the same as provided in the request.

Unless you have another solution for this case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are using the `requests` library? If you're doing something like `r = requests(url)` and then passing `r.text` to `lxml`, then you should still have access to `r.history` (which'll contain redirect history and your original url I believe) ?

Comment: Thanks Jon! I used the what you said and in r.history there is list which contains <Response [301]>. This will resolve my problem :)

Comment: Want to write a self-answer ?

Comment: Actually - found a good duplicate for others that might be wanting the same thing... saves either of us writing answers and this question might serve as a good signpost for it later - thanks for asking it.